# C# ret = Win32Sec.LsaAddAccountRights(lsaHandle, pSid, privileges, 1) error code 3221225485

Tags: c#-2.0

I got the full LSA code from PINVOKE.NET to do all the LSA calls.
the `ret = Win32Sec.LsaAddAccountRights(lsaHandle, pSid, privileges, 1);` is a value of 3221225485 only when I try to set `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege`.

```
public void AddPrivileges(string account, string privilege)
{
    uint ret = 0;
    IntPtr pSid = GetSIDInformation(account);
    LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] privileges = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];

    privileges[0] = InitLsaString(privilege);
    ret = Win32Sec.LsaAddAccountRights(lsaHandle, pSid, privileges, 1);

    try
    {
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            if (this._writeToConsole)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Added: {0} to {1} successfully.", account, privilege);
                LSA.WriteError("LsaWrapper::AddPrivleges", String.Format("Added: {0} to {1} successfully.", account, privilege), 0);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (ret == STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }

        if ((ret == STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) || (ret == STATUS_NO_MEMORY))
        {
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();
        }

        throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)ret));
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        string msg = "\r\nSource:\r\n\t" + er.Source + "\r\n" +
                "Stack trace:\r\n\t" + er.StackTrace + "\r\n" +
```

Comment: 3221225485 == 0xC000000D == STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER, "An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function".  There's no way to tell whether the arguments you pass are valid from the snippet.

Comment: it is the same information "account" and "privilege" for the other local machine privileges that work. all the work from what I can tell is in the function itself. and i'm sure the "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege" is right because it can read the current users/accounts.